# Batch apex not sending more emails

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, singleemailmessage

Below is my batch apex code,in this query if i put limit 1 - the mail is sending successfully . if i don't put any limit in query - mail sending failed .if query gets 5 records also -mail sending failed.how to achieve this.

```
global class DMSalertmail implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
   string query = 'SELECT Id,CreatedDate,Next_30_Days__c,Title FROM ContentVersion where Next_30_Days__c=53 ';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public List<ContentVersion> myContentVersion =new List<ContentVersion>();
global String body='';
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<ContentVersion> scope)
{
    for(ContentVersion cv : scope)
    {
        myContentVersion.add(cv);
        system.debug(myContentVersion);
    }

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstEmail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toadd=new String[]{'abc@gmail.com'};

    for(ContentVersion cv :myContentVersion)
    {
        if(cv.Next_30_Days__c!=Null && cv.Next_30_Days__c==53)
        {
            string b = 'File Name:'+cv.Title +' '+'This file have created 30 days back.';
             body += b ;
            mail1.setToAddresses(toadd);
            mail1.setSubject('DMS alert Mail');
            mail1.setHtmlBody(body);
            lstEmail.add(mail1);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail1 });
            System.debug(body);
        }
    }
    Messaging.SendEmail(lstEmail);
    system.debug(lstEmail);
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to work on that `for` loop. Since you're not instantiating new object for every email you want to send, same instance gets added in the list. Also `Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail1 });` should be removed since you're already adding all those emails in `lstEmail`

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstEmail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

String[] toadd=new String[]{'abc@gmail.com'};

for(ContentVersion cv :myContentVersion)
{
    if(cv.Next_30_Days__c!=Null && cv.Next_30_Days__c==53)
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        string b = 'File Name:'+cv.Title +' '+'This file have created 30 days back.';
         body += b ;
        mail1.setToAddresses(toadd);
        mail1.setSubject('DMS alert Mail');
        mail1.setHtmlBody(body);
        lstEmail.add(mail1);
    }
}
Messaging.SendEmail(lstEmail);
system.debug(lstEmail);
```

Comment: how to send more mails...

Comment: Mass email can only be sent to an address in a standard email field. Mass email using a custom email field is not supported. Instead of forming email body using Apex, try using visualforce email template and set whatId and toaddress accordingly.